# Bound property not assigned

Tags: xamarin.forms

My view...

```
public partial class TableRow : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TableRow), null);

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);

            lblValue.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

Used like this...

```
<Custom:TableRow NameText="Name" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

But when I set the binding context...

```
BindingContext = candidate;
```

... you've guessed it! Nothing happens!

What's the missing step?

It's the page's `BindingContext` that `candidate` is set to.

Comment: The BindingContext's scope matchs?

Comment: When the labels inside my custom row are inlined into the page, then `{Binding Name}`, for example, successfully binds to the label. But here, `Text` isn't even called.

Comment: So apparently the scopes don't matchs. It can be a ListView's like behavior, that set to each children a different binding context (The listview's BindingContext is a IEnumerable property, for example, and it's itens's Bindincontext is the current corresponding collection's object itself). Can you make clear this contexts in your question's code?

Comment: candidate is assigned to the page's context. Should it be on the tableview? I figured that table view would inherit the page's binding context.

Comment: 1) Is the `TableRow` showing up at all? Try setting its `BackgroundColor` to verify. 2) What are you sending the `BindingContext` on? 3) Are you sure `candidate.Name` isn't empty? 4) Does the `lblValue` show the desired text wherever it is?

Comment: 1) Yes, it's rendering. 2) I've set the bondage context on the page and the table. 3) Yes, it appears in a regular table row in the same table 4) No, lblValue is only set from the bound property - the setter isn't called at all.